# Nature of critical points of $f(x,y,z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

How can I study the nature of the critical points of $f(x,y,z)=3xy^2+6y^2+x^2z+3z^2$?

Since
$$
\begin{cases}
f'_x=3y^2+2xz\\
f'_y=6xy+12y\\
f'_z=x^2+6z
\end{cases}
$$
the only critical point is $(0,0,0)$.

The Hessian matrix is
$$
H_f(0,0,0)=\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 12 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 6
\end{matrix}\right),
$$
whose determinant is zero. Now I'm stuck, because I've tried to study $f$ along many restriction, and every time I realized that $O$ is a minimum, but I am not able to prove (or disprove) that $O$ is indeed a minimum.

What can I do now?

Comment: it seems like the critical point is neither min/max, try to look at it on a 3d graph visualizer

Comment: @tau_knight isn't the graph in 4 dimensions?

Comment: determine a specific value for $f$ and see how in looks on 3D.
for the point $(0,0,0)$ the value of $f$ is $f(0,0,0)=0$

Comment: @tau_knight I see, but this is not the graph...

Comment: Try to study a neighbourhood of $(0,0,0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z)=3xy^2+6y^2+x^2z+3z^2$ then $f\in C^{2}({\bf R})$. For $(x,y,z)\in {\bf R}^{3}$ then $\nabla f(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)\iff \begin{cases}2xz+3y^{2}=0,\\6xy+12y=0,\\x^{2}+6z=0 \end{cases}$. Thus ${\bf 0}:=(0,0,0)$ is indeed the only critical point. The Hessian matrix $H_f$ at ${\bf 0}$ is given by $H_f({\bf 0})=\left.\begin{pmatrix} 2z&6y&2x\\6y&6x+12&0\\2x&0&6\end{pmatrix}\right|_{{\bf 0}}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&12&0\\0&0&6\end{pmatrix}$, then $\det(H_f({\bf 0}))=0$ and the *Hessian-test* is inconclusive.

Thus, we need to review in the definition directely, considering that $f({\bf 0})=0$.

- If $x=y=0$, then $3z^{2}=f(x,y,z)>f({\bf 0})=0$ if $z\not=0$, so $f({\bf 0})$ is not local maximum.
- If $z=-x^{3}$ and $y=0$, then $x^{5}(3x-1)=f(x,y,z)<f({\bf 0})=0$ if $0<x<\frac{1}{3}$, so $f({\bf 0})$ is not a local mimimum.

Recall $f$ has a local minimum at $p$ iff there exists $B_\delta(a)\cap {\rm dom}(f)$ such that $f(x)\geqslant f(p)$ over that ball. Therefore, $f({\bf 0})=0$ can not be a extreme value of $f$, then it is a saddle point.

Comment: I don't follow this, I'm afraid. Why does every ball around the origin contain a point with $x$-coordinate greater than 3?

Comment: @mcd : I  think it works now .

Comment: That's very interesting @A. P. . You are right that the function has values greater and less than 0 in every ball round the origin, so it is a saddlepoint, but on every straight line through the origin the value of the function first rises above zero. If you ignore the  $y$-coordinate and take $f(x, z)= x^2z+3z^2$ as the height of a hill, you would see the land rising in front of you in every direction you looked (or dead flat in the $z=0$ direction), but walking along the path $z=-|x|^3$ would take you downhill. That's contrary to my intuition about saddlepoints (and hills)!

Answer (score 2):

$3xy^2 +6y^2$ is certainly nonnegative in small enough balls around the origin, but the other part isn’t obviously always nonnegative, so let’s work there.  It would be convenient to deal with homogeneous polynomials, probably.  So try curves of the form $(t, 0, at^2)$ for various values of $a$.

Comment: For $a=-1/2$ the other part is negative. Is that enough to say that $O$ is a saddle point?

Comment: @zar : Does it allow you to produce points arbitrarily close to the origin where the function values are less than $f(0,0,0)$?  That rules out the origin being a local minimum.  You’ve already ruled out local maximum by considering other paths.  So the only remaining option would be saddle point.